# "You don't have the permission to use this type of flag"

Tags: bug, flagging

I was trying to flag a question as very low quality, because I couldn't decide between "unclear what you're asking" and "asking to do your homework for you", but then I got this error message.

[image]

Why is that? Why would I get the choice in the list of something I can't choose? And also, is the word "the" OK?

Comment: I can’t answer the rest of your question, I’ve never even heard about this error msg before, but what I can tell you is *yes*, the word “the” is fine, because it’s talking about a specific, unique permission (the one to raise that type of flag). It would also be fine to drop the *the*, but that’s not obligatory by any means.

Comment: As an aside, the "very low quality" flag on questions is rarely used. Just flag as "off-topic" and choose a reason if you think it's worth closing.

Comment: Has the question been closed in the meantime?

Comment: @Helmar Yes. [Here you go](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423522/ethical-norms-with-regard-to-fundamental-rights), before it's deleted.

Comment: The question was closed five minutes *after* this meta post was made, so the question wasn't closed between the time you got the flag dialogue and the time you tried to submit it.  (That was my first guess.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ehm, I was not inquiring why the question couldn't be closed, or if my flagging had worked or not, but rather why I received the error message I did, which I never saw before. I already experienced the message "this question has already been closed; refresh the page to see the current status" when trying to close something, more than once.

Comment: Right.  I was pointing out that one thing that *didn't* happen is the question being closed while you were flagging.  It was open and yet you received this error.  I've seen errors sometimes when a closure (or deletion) slips in while you're doing something; that is not what happened here.  I am agreeing with you that the error is surprising.